# Not able to Access rest service deployed in EC2 from another EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have a rest application running in EC2 instance(say win1). I have another EC2 instance(say win2) running in the same VPC as win1. I'm not able to access/call the rest URL exposed in win1 from win2. I have configured the security the group to allow http request in inbound.
Security group rule:

```
Inbound:
Protocol    Port Range  Source  
HTTP (80)   TCP  80     0.0.0.0/0
HTTPS (443) TCP  443    0.0.0.0/0
```

In outbound i have enabled all traffic. The rest API exposed by win1 is

> `http://<IP>:9090/ui`

.

Answer (score 0):

you exposed port `9090` by win1, but security group, you just allow inbound port : `80` and `443` only.

You need :

Inbound:

```
Protocol    Port Range  Source  
HTTP (80)   TCP  80     0.0.0.0/0
Custom TCP  TCP 9090    0.0.0.0/0
HTTPS (443) TCP  443    0.0.0.0/0
```

Comment: Have tried that, It still doesnt seem to work. Is there any firewall settings that i need to enable?

Comment: pls check firewall is disabled or not in ec2 instance

Comment: please share the information how is REST API is working ?